# Why developerPayload field is empty when querying Purchases.subscriptions resource?

Tags: android, .net-core, google-play, android-billing

I'm implementing in-app subscriptions using *Google Play Billing Library*.
Everything works fine except one think, when I acknowledge purchase I set the **developerPayload** to some string value. Then I can see this value when querying purchases inside the app, but when I'm using Google Developer Api in my backend to verify subscriptions  the **developerPayload** field is empty, all other fields are correct.

My backend is written in .NET core 2.2 and I'm using *Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3* library.

I've also checked that with python library and the result is the same.

This is how I prepare my acknowledge params, ***developerPayload*** is just a simple string with about 60 characters.

```kotlin
val params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
.setDeveloperPayload(developerPayload)
.setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
.build()

billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params) { billingResult ->
...
}
```

Comment: A fix for this issue is rolling out shortly. Please see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133782951 for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I am Facing the same issue
That's the respond when i request the Google Api

> { kind: 'androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase',   startTimeMillis:
>   '1564065118619',   expiryTimeMillis: '1564065536468',   autoRenewing:
>   true,   priceCurrencyCode: 'SAR',   priceAmountMicros: '10990000',
>   countryCode: 'SA',   developerPayload: '',   paymentState: 1,
>   orderId: 'GPA.3399-9037-3439-13416',   purchaseType: 0,
>   acknowledgementState: 0 }

**And the could being sent from Android**

```
AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                        AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .setDeveloperPayload(String.valueOf(user.getId()))
                                .build();
mBillingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, this);
```